# SignatureNotFound with fog-aws and carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, fog-aws

I am using carrierwave and fog-aws while uploading a file to aws and storing the aws url in my local DB table.I have created `carrierwave.rb` file to config all fog-aws credentials.

```
begin
 CarrierWave.configure do |config|                      # required
 config.storage = :fog

 config.fog_credentials = {
  :provider               => 'AWS',       # required
  :aws_access_key_id      => 'Key_id',       # required
  :aws_secret_access_key  => 'access_key',       # required
  :region                 => 'us-west-2'  # o\tional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  # :fog                   => 'host',
  # :endpoint               => 'host'
 }
 config.fog_directory  = 'my-images-server' # required
 # see https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3
 # for more optional configuration
 config.fog_public     = true   # optional, defaults to true
```

My uploader file contains

```
class QueryUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
 storage :fog
 def store_dir
  base_dir = File.join(Rails.root, "public", "uploads")
  "#{base_dir}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
 end
 def cache_dir
  "/tmp/service-quep"
 end
 def extension_white_list
   %w(sql)
 end
end
```

I read many articles and breaking my head from 2days, still could not find any solution.My access key is without space and bucket name is not trailing with a slash.Can anyone please tell why this

> Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden) excon.error.response :body => "\n`SignatureDoesNotMatch`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.YTUUYUDTDYJBKJNUFYD

error is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, on this method you don't need to write extra code because of Rails directory mapping automatically like if you use `"uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"` then it automatically mapping `/public/uploads/...`

your code

```
def store_dir
    base_dir = File.join(Rails.root, "public", "uploads")
    "#{base_dir}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

it will be

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

You can check [`this gist`](https://gist.github.com/cblunt/1303386) this is great for working with Rails, CarrierWave and AWS, also you can [check this](https://gist.github.com/cblunt/1303386/b47377dfbddd7a29af087a64660464dfd35392d3)

Comment: Yeah its working but then i donot understan what is the issue with the old store directory?Can you please explain.

Comment: I think that's issue is overriding store directory because of I don't found anywhere with this which you wrote to your question, the ideal and valid is `public/...`  or `uploads/...` see this https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#changing-the-storage-directory

Comment: Yeah, it may be. Thanks a lot fool-dev